# How to mark detected objects in a new image?

Tags: image, rotation, caffe, detection

I'm trying to detect multiple vehicles in satellite and aerial images. I have two main questions:

1- After training the convolution network and getting the caffe model, how could I test it on a new image and mark the detected vehicles with sth like bounding boxes? Should I change the size of data blob to be able to use commands like this?

```
net.forward('new image')
```

[image: satellite image]

2- As you know the vehicles on the streets have different angles. Are deep learning techniques already rotation invariant? If not what can I do to deal with object's angles which can vary to 360 degrees?

I would appreciate if anyone guide me through this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [faster R-CNN](https://github.com/rbgirshick/py-faster-rcnn) base on caffe to train a vehicle detection model.

1. Different image sizes can be input in the faster R-CNN framework, and there is [demo code](https://github.com/rbgirshick/py-faster-rcnn/blob/master/tools/demo.py) for you to reference.
2. Because there are different angles vehicle in your training data, the trained model have the capacity to recognize these in new images.

Comment: Training on new objects, [SSD: Single Shot MultiBox Detector](http://arxiv.org/abs/1512.02325) is easier to work with.